# Oracle JDK 1.8 and community support timeline

Tags: java, java-8, timeline

Next major version for Java (Java 9) candidate release happened in August 2017.

I was reading one of the blogs where-in it is mentioned about the on going Oracle support for Java 8. The blog read...

[Redistribution of Java SE](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/faster-and-easier-use-and-redistribution-of-java-se)

> Oracle JDK 8 will continue to receive public updates for at least the
>   next year(blog published on September 2017), and commercial support will be available through 2025.

It has been mentioned about Public Updates being available till next year. (Sept/October 2018) and commercial support till 2025.

Does this mean, (say, if we go by the blog) **there will no Public Updates past 2018** and to get patches/fixes, one needs commercial support?

I am more interested in JRE as it is the most downloaded and used than JDK.

Why this question ?
Our application is built on Java and we ask the end user to download and install Oracle JRE 1.8. 
If the community update ends on 2018 as per blog, should we ask the customer to subscribe for commercial license?

We are evaluating Java 9 which just went RC and it will be too early for us.

Comment: side note: consider to ship the JRE along with your application e.g. using the javapackager tool.

Comment: @Puce After reading your comment I started to get information about javapackager tool. Can you say - can I put in generated self-contained application many jar files? Can it be used with OSGi application?

Comment: @Pavel_K Yes, you can package as many jars as you like and it should work with any Java program including OSGi. And with Java SE 9, javapackager will be able to use jlink to create a tailored JRE (just the modules you need).

Comment: If you plan to maintain your application and ensure Java 9 compatibility, once it has been released, there is no need to ask the customers to subscribe for commercial license as they can switch to Java 9 when Java 8 reaches end-of-life. You can be sure that public support for Java 8 will not be terminated before the Java 9 release. A delay of the Java 9 release will cause an extension of Java 8’s support, for sure. If you find an incompatibility, your customers need to update the application before switching, but having to install an update/fix when a bug has been found, is a normal procedure…

Comment: Thanks for the updates @Puce, We can't ship JRE for various reasons.

Comment: @Holger, We are considering moving to Java 9. Coming to Java 8, will it EOL(non commercial) on 2018 Sept if Java 9 is released as per schedule?